# how to resolve wifi disconnects and can't reconnect until disable and re-enable networking?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, network-manager, suspend

I don't know if this is something that already has a solution or not. I am running ubuntu 12.04 LTS and wireless driver rtl8187.

My wireless connection drops after a while (like an hour or so) and seems to occur after some period of inactivity from the mouse/keyboard.
I have tried disabling the automatic screen shutdown and by association the suspend and this has not resolved the issue.

In addition to the wireless connection dropping, it will not reconnect unless I disable and re-enable networking.
I do this from the GUI as I tend to have issues running network control commands via the command line if I run the network manager (which i like to use to monitor the network status via the tray icon when using the computer).

If there is any way to maintain the network connectivity I would be much obliged.

Thanks in advance,
-Jared

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: See my answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/665721/how-to-rotate-wifi-connections

Answer (score 0):

First of all find out the name of the driver you are using then open a terminal with ctrl-alt-t the type this
This worked Here is a technique that sometimes works:

gksudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config Add a single line:

SUSPEND_MODULES="your network driver name" Proofread, save and close gedit. Reboot

Comment: You find the driver by sudo lshw -C network

the line driver = 'the driver', the driver is what you use in that line

SUSPEND_MODULES="the driver"